# How to make bold part of text , passed from object to react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This  is the page html where I create the object. Part of description must be bold:

```
const agencyProps = {
  title: "Managed agency selection",
  paragraph: "Strengten your onboarding process",
  videoImage: {
    src: "/img/video.png",
    alt: "background",
    width: 330,
    height: 520,
  },

  selections: {
    cardOne: {
      title: "Brief",
      bold: "THIS",
      description: `Complete brief or simple guidance on what to include, we've got you covered`,
      width: "430px",
    },

    cardTwo: {
      title: "Search",
      description:
        "In-depth agency search covering, criteria matching, door knocking and due-dilligence vetting.",
      width: "460px",
    },

    cardThree: {
      title: "Pitch",
      description:
        "Comprehensive pitch management, including comms, diary management and pitch hosting.",
      width: "490px",
    },
  },
};
```

This is the component, where I pass the object property:

```
<StyledCard style={{ maxWidth: `${selections.cardTwo.width}` }}>
              <StyledIconWrapper>
                <FaSearch size="1x" color="#0f0f0f" />
              </StyledIconWrapper>
              <StyledTitleDescriptionWrapper>
                <StyledSelectTitle>
                  {selections.cardTwo.title}
                </StyledSelectTitle>
                <StyledSelectDescription>
                  {selections.cardTwo.description}
                </StyledSelectDescription>
              </StyledTitleDescriptionWrapper>
            </StyledCard>
```

I've tried to put in `<b></b>` the part which I like, tried with making getter and using "this" with property 'bold' but still cant manage to catch the words which i like to be bold.
Hope explanation is ok and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to wrap the text to be bold in a `<strong>` tag, e.g.:

```
cardOne: {    
    description: "This text is <strong>bold</strong>.",
    title: // ...
    width: // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `<strong> <strong/>` tag and pass that to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`
more information on this [page](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<strong>` or `<b>` tags around the part of the description you want bolded.

```
cardOne: {
    title: "Brief",
    description: `Complete brief or <b>simple guidance</b> on what to include, we've got you covered`,
    width: "430px"
  };
```

Then you can render the description with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: cardOne.description }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the description to a React fragment and use the `<strong>` element to wrap the bold text.

```js
cardTwo: {
  title: "Search",
  description:
    <>In-depth agency search <strong>covering</strong>, criteria matching, door knocking and due-dilligence vetting.</>,
  width: "460px",
},
```

Comment: Thanks alot people ! I done it with Unmitigated solution, didn`t knew i can pass it like that .

Answer (score 0):

there is also this npm package you can use. you can map through your obj and if the bold attribute is needed replace the text or part of it with your styled text.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-string-replace

```
obj.map(item => (
                      <YOURLIST>
                                {reactStringReplace(
                                  item.DESCRIPTION,
                                  item.DESCRIPTION,
                                  match => (
                                    <span style={{fontWeight:bold}}>{match}</span>
                                  )
                                )}
                     </YOURLIST>
))
```